# register custom hibernate validator with entitymanager

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-validator

I've written a custom validator annotation and a validator class for it. But when I call entitymanager.persist() the custom validation does not trigger. What am I missing to get the entitymanager to trigger my custom validator?

When I run my tests I can see the @NotNull and @Size built-in validations getting called during entitymanager.persist(), but my custom validator is never being called. How do I hook this up?

Don't pay too much attention to the actual validation I'm doing. I'm just trying to get it wired up and triggering on persist.

Here is a snippet of the annotation:

```
import mypackage.validation.PasswordValidator;

@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Password {
    String message() default "{Invalid password}";

    Class[] groups() default {};

    Class[] payload() default {};
}
```

Here is a snippet version of the the validator:

```
package mypackage.validation;

import mypackage.annotation.Password;

public class PasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Password, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Password passwordAnnotation) {
        // TODO noop for now
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String password, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is a snippet of a simple class I annotate:

```
import mypackage.validation.annotation.Password;


@GeneratePojoBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "mycatalog")
public class User extends DatabaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 58608923641104636L;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(max = 128)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    // use @Column(length =...) instead of @Size here because password
    // length will change after salting and hashing
    @Column(length = 102)
    @Password
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see your validator invoked when manually validating an instance of your entity via `Validator#validate()`?

Comment: Good question...and no I don't see it when I manually invoke the validator. I stepped through the code into the hibernate validator code (hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final) and as I went through I saw the metaconstraints collected into a set (line 378 of org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl. It had the my fields and their constraints (the non-custom ones eg: @NotNull). But it was missing my custom @Password constraint. I don't know how to make hibernate aware of my custom constraint. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct type parameters for the constraint annotation type and the target data type when implementing `ConstraintValidator`:

```
public class PasswordValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<Password, String> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh...my bad. i don't know why when i copy and pasted it lost the type parameters...so that doesn't seem to be the issue. i've corrected the code i posted.....errr weird...actually the original post i made is correct, but the type parameters don't show up in the rendered <pre><code> output.  ???

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I'm running my tests using Arquillian and ShrinkWrap. I create a test war file to be deployed and run my tests. I forget to add the new validation annotation and validator classes to me ShrinkWrap war file. That's why the validations weren't sorry.